# Is it possible to render Annotations made in View Space?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, annotation

I have some animated annotations made in the 3D Viewport and I cannot render them with viewport render. It looks like the problem is that they were made in View Space.

[image]

Is there any way to have them rendered?

Comment: Well, it seems that annotations are rendered in viewport render... can you add more information about your context?

Comment: As a comment: yes, you can always convert it to Grease Pencil, but it's going to be misplaced (at least if you annotated in View Space) and you cannot edit the thickness of the strokes.

Comment: @lemon Well, I didn't tested in a new file... I guess I'll have to edit the post. It looks like View Space annotations won't render. You think I may report this as a bug?

Comment: ok, you're right: does not render in view space, it seems... about reporting I don't know, you can do it anyway.

Comment: Do you have under the Objects properties-visibility-Show in Render enabled